# Drawing UML Diagrams with many variables

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Can I know any other way of representing Variables in UML other than `variablename:type`. Since my class has a huge number of Variables.

Comment: If your class has "a huge number of Variables", you should think about your design and not about other ways of drawing it.

Comment: Thank You Your answer was not  really helpful

Comment: ...but @sergej is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways of representing class attributes in a UML (2.5) class diagram:

#### 1:

[image]

#### 2:

[image]

#### Note:

It is *not mandatory* to show all class attributes in a class digram.
You could, for example, show the public attributes only and hide the rest.
Think about for whom you are drawing this diagram. Which attributes are shown depends on the target reader.

But, if your class has a huge number of attributes and want to show them all, then it is going to be a huge class diagram.

Comment: These are actually slightly different in the UML repository. The attribute by itself does not involve an instance of the `Association` metaclass. The association-end property does, however, and it also creates an unnamed opposite-end property owned by `Door`. (Of course, this all goes to hell if you're using the crappy new dot notation in UML. In that case, the association owns both ends when no dot is visible.)